# Get a list of values from another model

Tags: python, django, model

I installed a third party app which has basically 5 fields: id, name, state, geocode, geometry.

I created a new app which I need to import only the values from the 'name' field from the other model.

So I basically did this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from brasil_municipios.models import Municipio #which is the third party app

class Escritorio(models.Model):
    nomeescritiorio = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cidade = models.OneToOneField(Municipio.objects.values_list('name').order_by('name')[0:10], on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
```

And got this error:

```
AssertionError: OneToOneField(<QuerySet [('ABADIA DE GOIÁS',), ('ABADIA DOS DOURADOS',), ('ABADIÂNIA',), ('ABAETETUBA',), ('ABAETÉ',), ('ABAIARA',), ('ABARÉ',), ('ABATIÁ',), ('ABAÍRA',), ('ABDON BATISTA',)]>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

I already tried others ways to solve the issue, using filter(), get() and etc, but all get the same error in all of them.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do. Why are you passing a `values_list` as the destination of a OneToOneField? That's not how it works at all.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for you reply. The third party app has a model with the field ('name') which is populated with thousands of values. I trying to get the values from this field to another new model.

Comment: Yes, which you do with `models.OneToOneField(Municipio)`. There is no reason to use `values_list` here.

Comment: Daniel, I tried this way but the new field get the values from the 5 fields from the first model: id, name, state, geocode, geometry, not only from the field 'name' which is the one I want.

Comment: Really, that isn't how it works. The *value* is the ID of the row in the Municipio table. If you want to change how it displays *in a form*, you can change the definition of the `__str__` method of the Municipio model.

Comment: @ViniciusCruvinel may I kindly suggest you learn about relational databases ? Django's ORM is only a thin wrapper around your database, so if you don't understand relational databases, you can't use Django models properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a new app which I need to import only the values from the 'name' field from the other model.

You don't "import the values from another model" - that's not how it works. What you do is link models together so that the underlying "escritorio" table records know the primary key of the "municipio" table record they are related to (that's what the `OneToOneField` is doing actually). Then, from the foreign key stored in "escritorio", you can read the related "municipio" record's "name" value.

IOW, you just pass the related model's name to the `OneToOne` field, and then you can get the related Municipio name from an `Escritorio` instance just following the relationship, ie `escrotorio.cidade.name`.

If you most often need to use this value when working with `Escritorio` models, you can optimize for readability by adding a read-only property to `Escritorio`:

```
class Escritorio(models.Model):
    nomeescritiorio = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cidade = models.OneToOneField(Municipio, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.cidade.name
```

which allows you to just write `escritorio.name` (simple shortcut, really)

AND you certainly want to optimize for performances by forcing the ORM to always load the related `municipio` values when loading `escritorio` so you have everything in a single db query instead of needing one query to get the `escritorio` and a second for the related `municipio`. You do this by [using `select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), either directly when you know you'll need the names, or systematically by providing a custom manager and queryset class for your  `Escritorio` model.

**NB**: you will of course have to create escritorio instances for each of the municipio record you're interested in - neither django nor your rdmbs will automagically do this for you.